# How to remove keys of array?

Tags: php

```
Array(
   [0] => =>
   [1] => ['configtimetosee'] => 'Período de inatividade, em minutos, que determina a exclusão do usuário da lista.';

   [2] => ['online_users:addinstance'] => 'Adicionar novo bloco de usuários on-line';

   [3] => ['online_users:myaddinstance'] => 'Adicionar um novo bloco de usuários online ao Painel';

   [4] => ['online_users:viewlist'] => 'Ver lista de usuários online';

   [5] => ['periodnminutes'] => 'últimos {$a} minutos';

   [6] => ['pluginname'] => 'Usuários Online';

   [7] => ['timetosee'] => 'Remover após inatividade (minutos)';
)
```

in result, I need this output:

```
Array(
   [configtimetosee] => Período de inatividade, em minutos, que determina a exclusão do usuário da lista.
   [online_users:addinstance] => Adicionar novo bloco de usuários on-line
   [online_users:myaddinstance] => Adicionar um novo bloco de usuários online ao Painel
   [online_users:viewlist] => Ver lista de usuários online
   [periodnminutes] => últimos {$a} minutos
   [pluginname] => Usuários Online
   [timetosee] => Remover após inatividade (minutos)
)
```

Comment: `unset($array['key_you_want_to_remove']);`

Comment: `unset($myArray[$myKey])`

Comment: Does this PHP function work? [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: You have no question in your question body. If those "keys" are part of the array values then you need to use a regex for it.

Comment: I dont see the difference between ur given array and result/expected array

Comment: Qual e a chave do seu array.  Voce tem `[6] => ['pluginname'] => 'Usuários Online';`, a chave e `[6]` ou  `['pluginname']`.  Transaltion, what is the key in your array `[6]` ou  `['pluginname']`.

Comment: So you want to turn a numerically-indexed multidimensional array (where each row contains a single, string-indexed array) into a string-indexed single-dimension array?

Comment: In an array of string-indexed-single-dimension arrays ... I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an original array like this:

```
$original_array = array(
    array('configtimetosee' => 'Período de inatividade, em minutos, ...'),
    array('online_users:addinstance' => 'Adicionar novo bloco de ...'),
    // etc.
);
```

And you're trying to eliminate the extra array layer to get output like this:

```
$new_array = array(
    'configtimetosee' => 'Período de inatividade, em minutos...',
    'online_users:addinstance' => 'Adicionar novo bloco de ...'
    // etc.
);
```

Then this code should do it:

```
foreach ($original_array as $row) {     // loop over the array of arrays
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {  // loop over each sub-array (even if just 1 item)
        $new_array[$key] = $value;      // set the output array key to the value    
    }
}
```

One thing to watch out for with this, is that if you have any duplicated keys in the sub-arrays, they will be overwritten in your new array, and you'll just get the value of the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
  [1] => array( "shallala" => "lalalala",
                "xyz" => "..." ) ;
```

so make an array

```
 $newArr = array();

 foreach($oldArray as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $key => $value){
        $newArr[$key] = $value;
    }
 }
```